# How to un-pivot from table in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have 1-5 slabs for Progressive discount. The slabs could vary from one transaction to another. I want to store all the five values in 5 variables.

My table is like this.

[image]

Expected values are like this

[image]

Example:2

If my table is like this

[image]

Expected values are like this

[image]

Example:3

If my table is like this

[image]

Expected values are like this

[image]

There can be only one or two slabs as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so is this 0 based start or 1?  Discount is 1 slab is 0...

Comment: You also have overlap  Is slab_to of 100 in discount 1 or 5?

Comment: Slabs should overlap. Slab_to of 100 is 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pivot on multiple columns of an Oracle row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939244/using-pivot-on-multiple-columns-of-an-oracle-row)

Comment: Why sin't there a 4th discount if there are 4 slabs?

Comment: The number of slab could vary from one transaction to another. It could have 5 rows for a transaction. As per rule, it should be from 1 to 5 rows.

Comment: I get that: but each slab should have it's own discount right?  So your example shows 3 rows/records.  However expected results show 4 slabs and 3 discounts.  I would expect to see 3 slabs given 3 data rows.. My updated answer should be close; I just need to understand why you have 4 slabs

Comment: And... if all 5 rows were present. what happens then to the max(slab_to) value it gets ignored?

Comment: No. That's Slab5. I need to capture that as well.

Comment: I'm unable to assist any further.  I don't understand the requirements well enough at this stage.  It makes no sense to me from a pattern standpoint why you have 4 slabs in your example and 3 discounts given you only have 3 records in your sample data.  I see no effort in explaining why this is.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain it further.

Comment: I still don't know why in example 1 you have 4 slabs and only 3 discounts when only 3 records exist in sample data.  Why 4 SLABS?  you only have 3 RECORDS!   However, moving on; why doesn't the proposed answer work?  What's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi column pivot not an unpivot:

```
--BUILD Sample dataset called MyTable 
WITH MyTable as (
SELECT 0 slab_from, 100 slab_to, 1 discount FROM dual union all
SELECT 100 slab_from, 200 slab_to, 5 discount FROM dual union all
SELECT 200 slab_from, 99999999 slab_to, 8 discount FROM dual ),

--Now build a CTE with a row number that we can use to pivot the data.
CTE as (SELECT Slab_from, Discount, row_number() over (Order by slab_FROM) RN 
     FROM myTable)

--Now build the data set.  Though I'm a bit confused why there are 4 slabs and 3 discounts in your expected results...

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CTE)
PIVOT (
max(slab_from) as SLAB, max(Discount) as Discount --[We could add max(Slab_to) SLABTO] to get the max value for each as well if needed...
for RN in (1,2,3,4,5)  --RowNumber values 1-5 since 5 is max according to question
);
```

The above gives us:

```
+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| 1_SLAB | 1_DISCOUNT | 2_SLAB | 2_DISCOUNT | 3_SLAB | 3_DISCOUNT | 4_SLAB | 4_DISCOUNT | 5_SLAB | 5_DISCOUNT |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|      0 |          1 |    100 |          5 |    200 |          8 |        |            |        |            |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
```

If you want the column names to begin 0 just subtract 1 from the RN in the CTE.

Possible Answer 2: Tweeked: assuming all slab ranges start at 0 and that 1-5 are reserved for actual rows that may/maynot be in your base table.

```
--BUILD Sample dataset called MyTable 
WITH MyTable as (
SELECT 0 slab_from, 100 slab_to, 1 discount FROM dual union all
SELECT 100 slab_from, 200 slab_to, 5 discount FROM dual union all
SELECT 200 slab_from, 99999999 slab_to, 8 discount FROM dual),

--Now build a CTE with a row number that we can use to pivot the data.
CTE as (SELECT 0 "0_SLAB", Slab_to, Discount, row_number() over (Order by slab_FROM) RN 
     FROM myTable)

--Now build the data set.  Though I'm a bit confused why there are 4 slabs and 3 discounts in your expected results...

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CTE)
PIVOT (
max(slab_to) as SLAB, max(Discount) as Discount --[We could add max(Slab_to) SLABTO] to get the max value for each as well if needed...
for RN in (1,2,3,4,5)  --RowNumber values 1-5 since 5 is max according to question
);
```

The only difference here is I use slab_to and I hardcode 0_SLAB to 0 so all other possible ranges adjust from 1-5.

Columns are prefixed instead of suffixed but that's how the pivot does it.  and they are not in order of all slabs first followed by all discounts; but again; that's how the pivot does it; but column order and name I wouldn't think would matter so long as the data is right and repeatable.

But I still struggle with why the pivots' needed..  You have the data needed in a row based table that is normalized, extract the data iterate though it in the application and present it I don't know why we need the data to be pivoted.

Comment: Thank you. I also arrived at the Possible Answer 2.