# Display rows as columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has the following structure and sample data:

| VENDOR | ORDER | DELIVERY_DATE | REMARKS | USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 20-DEC-22 | OPENED | John |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 22-DEC-22 | REQUESTED | Martin |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 26-DEC-22 | IN PROCESS | Wyatt |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 10-JAN-23 | DELAYED | Khabib |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 22-JAN-23 | IN TRANSIT | Karen |

Table could contain different VENDORs and ORDERs. I need to display in one row data for each order and vendor.
Like this:

| VENDOR | ORDER | DELIVERY_DATE_1 | REMARKS_1 | USER_1 | DELIVERY_DATE_2 | REMARKS_2 | USER_2 | DELIVERY_DATE_3 | REMARKS_3 | USER_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PEPSI | 1122 | 20-DEC-22 | OPENED | John | 22-DEC-22 | REQUESTED | Martin | 26-DEC-22 | IN PROCESS | Wyatt |

etc

I've tried PIVOT, but it does not work:

```
SELECT VENDOR,
         order_number,
        -- delivery_date,
         pickup_date
         reasonf_of_delay,
         user_name
from table
PIVOT
(count(delivery_date)
 FOR order_number
 )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using pivot on multiple columns of an Oracle row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939244/using-pivot-on-multiple-columns-of-an-oracle-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build something similar with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE VENDOR_ORDERS (
    VENDOR VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER,
    DELIVERY_DATE DATE,
    REMARKS VARCHAR2(50),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO VENDOR_ORDERS VALUES ('PEPSI', 1122, TO_DATE('20-DEC-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'OPENED', 'John');
INSERT INTO VENDOR_ORDERS VALUES ('PEPSI', 1122, TO_DATE('22-DEC-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'REQUESTED', 'Martin');
INSERT INTO VENDOR_ORDERS VALUES ('PEPSI', 1122, TO_DATE('26-DEC-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'IN PROCESS', 'Wyatt');
INSERT INTO VENDOR_ORDERS VALUES ('PEPSI', 1122, TO_DATE('10-JAN-2023', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DELAYED', 'Khabib');
INSERT INTO VENDOR_ORDERS VALUES ('PEPSI', 1122, TO_DATE('22-JAN-2023', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'IN TRANSIT', 'Karen');

SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT VENDOR
           ,ORDER_NUMBER
           ,DELIVERY_DATE
           ,REMARKS
           ,USER_NAME
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VENDOR, ORDER_NUMBER ORDER BY DELIVERY_DATE ASC) AS  rn
     FROM VENDOR_ORDERS vo
) DS
PIVOT
(
     MAX(DELIVERY_DATE) AS DT, MAX(REMARKS) AS R, MAX(USER_NAME) AS UN FOR RN IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
) PVT
```

[image]

The issue is that the PIVOT columns are static in this way. So, you can add 10 or 20 which is most in your case and have NULL value if such records do not exists.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to use ***PIVOT clause*** as you started to do.
But, you need to add as many aggregate measures as you have columns (DELIVERY_DATE, REMARKS, USER#).
Also, you need to rank (row_number) all the rows per VENDOR, ORDER# before using PIVOT clause like below.
Finally, you can ***change aliases*** produced by PIVOT clause for your columns in the upper SELECT.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT T.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VENDOR, ORDER# ORDER BY DELIVERY_DATE, ROWNUM) RN
   FROM TAB_NAME T
) PIVOT(
  MAX(DELIVERY_DATE) AS DELIVERY_DATE
, MAX(REMARKS) AS REMARKS
, MAX(USER#) AS USER#
   FOR RN IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
);
```

[*demo on db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/IEq7zW64)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for pivot. For instance: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

If you wish to pivot you must know for which values returned for a column in a row you will have different columns. Using plain SQL and not dynamic SQL you can't have an undetermined number of columns. I did not really understand what columns your SQL must return.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Vendor, 'Order 1' AS OrderNumber, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Delivery_Date END) AS Delivery_Date_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Remarks END) AS Remarks_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN User END) AS User_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Delivery_Date END) AS Delivery_Date_2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Remarks END) AS Remarks_2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN User END) AS User_2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Delivery_Date END) AS Delivery_Date_3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Remarks END) AS Remarks_3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN User END) AS User_3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN Delivery_Date END) AS Delivery_Date_4,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN Remarks END) AS Remarks_4,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN User END) AS User_4,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN Delivery_Date END) AS Delivery_Date_5,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN Remarks END) AS Remarks_5,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN User END) AS User_5 FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor, Order ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum FROM [[your_table]]
```

) t
WHERE Order = 1122
GROUP BY Vendor

! Not sure about your use case, but this might work. If you have a lot of data, I would suggest creating a new table and inserting with transformations.

Comment: The above is a wrong usage of rownum. Because rownum represents the order in which the row was found in the database and not something you may rely on.